# Protocol Host showing in our Error Log / 404 Errors

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, lamp, error-log

I'm getting an error showing up in my error logs over and over.  I see it in an error log in cpanel as well as in an AW stats report.

The errors look like this:

```
/my_directory/'%20+%20protocol_host%20+%20'/images/greenthumb.png
/my_directory/'%20+%20protocol_host%20+%20'/images/imgsicon.png
```

I'm seeing this thousands of times a day.

the legit path in the example above would be something like this:

```
/my_directory/page.php?id=123454
(i.e www.my_site.com/my_directory/page.php?id=123454)
```

Any ideas what this protocol_host is referring to and why it would be hitting my error log so often?

My research before posting this question led me to something related to the search indexer on a windows operating system computer, but I can't see the connection.

Thanks in advance as always

Comment: Can you use a command line tool such as grep to find the pattern protocol_host somewhere in your codebase?

`grep -rn protocol_host ./directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with @Shal. Although google gives you some results for 'protocol_host' I don't think that they are related to your problem. I guess it is either an error in your PHP code which generates the links or an erroneous client (or a hacker) is accessing your site

Comment: +1. If they outnumber the requests for actual pages, then very likely  from an external source.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I'll give that grep a try and see what i see and follow up back here after.

Comment: The grep yeiled no results, so I'm nowhere on this right now.  Perhaps it's just over my head.

Comment: Have a look at your web server log files. Which IP produces the log messages?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error-URLs, it seems like the paths to some images are generated dynamically by concatenating strings; but the quotes are note set correctly.

`/my_directory/'%20+%20protocol_host%20+%20'/images/greenthumb.png`
without URL encoding is
`/my_directory/' + protocol_host + '/images/greenthumb.png`

PHP uses `.` to concatenate strings, but here a `+` is used. So I would guess that some JavaScript code causes this error.

Check your JS resources!

Comment: You have my +1 since I was going to post exactly this explanation. Furthermore, the javascript should be something like `'/my_directory/' + protocol_host + '/images/greenthumb.png'` instead of the URL without encoding @king_nak posted. Even more, %20 is (as far as I know) only generated automatically from the space in the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, that you are linking some resources relatively without a leading slash.

example:

```
<img src="images/foo.png" />
```

usually this leads to urls like `http://example.com/images/foo.png` instead of `http://example.com/my_project/images/foo.png` but can have other conseques as well.

This is just a guess though.